# ¿Como importo paquetes de una una subcarpeta a una carpeta? En python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Supongamos que cada carpeta/ paquete ya tiene su respectivo **init**.py

Si tengo esta composición:

```
-Carpeta Padre
|   archivo1.py
|   
|   Carpeta Hija
|     | 
      |archivo2.py
|     |_____________
|
|____________________
```

Quisiera importar desde archivo2.py las cosas de archivo1.py, obviamente cuando hago from Carpetapadre import archivo1.py no funciona.

Si no es mucha molestia me podrian explicar para que sirve el "." y ".." porque he visto en algunos lugares que hacen from .. import Xcosa, lo intente y tampoco me resultó. Uso python 2.7

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Aaron David, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1):

Con esto importas todo el archivo archivo2 lo debes hacer sin él .py

```
 from carpeta_hija import archivo2
```

Y para importar los módulos del archivo 2, para llamar a cosas del archivo2 debes indicarlo al principio.

```
archivo2.modulo()
```